# Not localhost datetime but database datetime while inserting entity to database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble inserting a new record into my PostgreSQL database. I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. I am connecting to an external database. The time on this server is different than on my localhost. When I insert a new entity into the database, this record is inserted with the date and time from my local host and not from the database server. I know I can set a datetime zone in application.properties, but if I change the database connection URL I may not know what time is set on the database server. I know I can get the now () time from the database before saving it, but I'm sure there is another solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: How is date and time inserted? Does the column have a default-value like now()?

Comment: I changed type in database from "timestamp without time zone" to "timestamp with time zone" and add default value now(). From code I set "LocalDateTime.now()" and all works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with this situation is to use the data type `timestamp with time zone` in PostgreSQL. Then timestamps are stored as *absolute time*, independent from the time zone (I know that this sort of contradicts the name of the data type). Then all you need to do is to set the database parameter `timezone` to the correct client time zone in each database session.

Let's assume that the database server is in New York, but we are in Calcutta:

```
CREATE TABLE tstest (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   t timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

SET timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';

INSERT INTO tstest (t) VALUES (current_timestamp);

SELECT * FROM tstest;

 id │                t                 
════╪══════════════════════════════════
  1 │ 2022-02-23 14:00:19.555188+05:30
(1 row)
```

Now somebody in Los Angeles accesses the data:

```
SET timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

SELECT * FROM tstest;

 id │               t               
════╪═══════════════════════════════
  1 │ 2022-02-23 00:30:19.555188-08
(1 row)
```

So everybody sees the correct timestamp, independent from where the server is located.